# C++ newbie: writing a function for extracting i vectors from a file. How do I get i/unkown number of vectors out of the function?

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, parameter-passing, argument-passing

I am writing a function for getting datasets from a file and putting them into vectors.  The datasets are then used in a calculation.  In the file, a user writes each dataset on a line under a heading like 'Dataset1'.  The result is i vectors by the time the function finishes executing.  The function works just fine.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the vectors out of the function!  (1) I think I can only return one entity from a function.  So I can't return i vectors.  Also, (2) I can't write the vectors/datasets as function parameters and return them by reference because the number of  vectors/datasets is different for each calculation.  If there are other possibilities, I am unaware of them.

I'm sure this is a silly question, but am I missing something here?  I would be very grateful for any suggestions.  Until now, I have not put the vector/dataset extraction code into a function; I have kept it in my main file, where it has worked fine.  I would now like to clean up my code by putting all data extraction code into its own function.

For each calculation, I DO know the number of vectors/datasets that the function will find in the file because I have that information written in the file and can extract it.  Is there some way I could use this information?

Comment: Things like exactly how a "dataset" or a "vector" is written in a file (on a "line") are not at all clear. You should probably paste some example data into the question, to make it clearer how it's organized and what your "vectors" really are.

Comment: It sounds like you may have the vectors stored in a plain array.  Is that true?

Comment: Thanks.  The vectors are like: std::vector<double> dataset1.  And each element is a number (double).  In the file, the data appears as: '1.0' '2.0' 3.2', etc, with each element made up of the number between ''.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each vector is of the same type you can return a 
`std::vector<std::vector<datatype> >`

This would look like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<datatype> > function(arguments) {  
    std::vector<std::vector<datatype> > return_vector;
    for(int i =0; i < rows; ++i) {
       \\ do processing
       return_vector.push_back(resulting_vector);
    }
    return return_vector;
}
```

Comment: Hi Serdalis.  Thanks.  They are of the same type.  Are you saying that your solution would return all vectors of that type?

Comment: It would return a vector of vectors of that type, which is what you want, i believe.

Comment: Thanks Benoit.  Sorry for the silly question, but would I have to make the vectors into a vector of vectors in the function first?

Comment: @Ant Benoit is correct, this would return a vector of size `i` containing all `i` vectors, but this code will only work if the `i` vectors are of the same type, etc. `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` would return a vector of string type vectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I had not heard of this.  In the function, I am actually getting other data as well as the datasets I mentioned.  And these other data are of the same type as the datasets.  But I will keep the datasets separate from the other data by writing a function inside the main function.  I will return the vector of vectors from both.

Comment: One way I get around this type of limitation is by passing in a struct as a reference, this struct will contain any datatypes i need returned and can be accessed outside the method, you can do the same if you wish.

Comment: Thank you, Serdalis.  That is interesting to know.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentionned, you may simply use a vector of vectors.

In addition, you may want to add a smart pointer around it, just to make sure you're not copying the contents of your vectors (but that's already an improvement. First aim at something that works).

As for the information on the number of vectors, you may use it by resizing the global vector to the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks Benoit.  By "copying," do you mean there is a risk that I would unnecessarily use resources by copying the vectors somewhere?

Comment: It will unnecessarily use twice the needed size in memory for a short time. The real loss here is the time used to copy the first version of the vector (of vectors) to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You question is, at its essence "How do I return a pile of *things* from a function?" It happens that your *things* are `vector<double>`, but that's not really important. What is important is that you have a pile of them of unknown size.

You can refine your thinking by rephrasing your one question into two:

- How do I represent a pile of *things*?
- How do I return that representation from a function?

As to the first question, this is precisely what ***containers*** do. Containers, as you surely know because you are already using one, hold an arbitrary numbers of similar objects. Examples include `std::vector<T>` and `std::list<T>`, among others. Your choice of which container to use is dictated by circumstances you haven't mentioned -- for example, how expensive are the items to copy, do you need to delete an item from middle of the pile, etc.

In your specific case, knowing what little we know, it seems you should use `std::vector<>`.  As you know, the template parameter is the type of the thing you want to store. In your case that happens to be (coincidentally), an `std::vector<double>`.  (The fact that the container and its contained object happen to be similar types is of no consequence. If you need a pile of Blobs or Widgets, you say `std::vector<Blob>` or `std::vector<Widget>`. Since you need a pile of `vector<double>`s, you say `vector<vector<double> >`.) So you would declare it thus:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double > > myPile;
```

(Notice the space between `>` and `>`. That space is required in the previous C++ standard.)

You build up that vector just as you did your `vector<double>` -- either using generic algorithms, or invoking `push_back`, or some other way.  So, your code would look like this:

```
void function( /* args */ ) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > myPile;
    while( /* some condition */ ) {
        std::vector<double> oneLineOfData;
        /* code to read in one vector */
        myPile.push_back(oneLineOfData);
    }
}
```

In this manner, you collect all of the incoming data into one structure, `myPile`.

As to the second question, how to return the data. Well, that's simple -- use a `return` statement.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > function( /* args */ ) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > myPile;
    /* All of the useful code goes here*/
    return myPile;
}
```

Of course, you could also return the information via a passed-in reference to your vector:

```
void function( /* args */, std::vector<std::vector<double> >& myPile)
{
    /* code goes here. including: */
    myPile.push_back(oneLineOfData);
}
```

Or via a passed-in pointer to your vector:

```
void function( /* args */, std::vector<std::vector<double> >* myPile)
{
    /* code goes here. */
    myPile->push_back(oneLineOfData);
}
```

In both of those cases, the caller must create the vector-of-vector-of-double before invoking your function. Prefer the first (`return`) way, but if your program design dictates, you can use the other ways.